# filtering src attribute of iframe in ios

Tags: iphone, iframe, filter, src

I have a website that allows the user to embed their videos using  tags such as .

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/se2P7hjPanE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

actually this iframe string is coming from service like this

```
    <br />
 \n&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;314&#39;&#39;
   src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com/embed/se2P7hjPanE&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; 
  allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

how can i get my original iframe string how to parse the src value and may be other values also to load video actually i used MWfeedparser(https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) but iam not getting like this

```
     <iframe width="560" height="314'' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/se2P7hjPanE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

after height attribute i got (' ')instead of "

how can i resolve this issue

i want to get src value from above frame i want to play that video in webview of iphone

so that i want to play that particular video (which the client uploaded) in my iphone .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
NSString *myString = @"&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;314&#39;&#39; src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
NSRange firstRange = [myString rangeOfString:@"http://"];
NSRange secondRange = [[myString substringFromIndex:firstRange.location] rangeOfString:@"&quot;"];
NSRange finalRange = NSMakeRange(firstRange.location, secondRange.location);
NSString *subString = [myString substringWithRange:finalRange];
NSLog(@"subString :: %@",subString);
```